# How should you use scaled weights with svydesign() in the survey package in R?

Tags: r, survey, survey-weights

I am using the [survey package](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/) in R to analyse the ["Understanding Society"](https://www.understandingsociety.ac.uk/) social survey. The [main user guide](https://www.understandingsociety.ac.uk/sites/default/files/downloads/documentation/mainstage/user-guides/mainstage-user-guide.pdf) for the dataset specifies (on page 45) that the weights have been scaled to have a mean of 1. When using the `svydesign()` function, I am passing the weight variable to the `weight` argument.

In the [survey package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf), under the `surveysummary()` function, it states:

> Note that the design effect will be incorrect if the weights have been rescaled so that they are not reciprocals of sampling probabilities.

**Will I therefore get incorrect estimates when using functions such as `svyglm()` etc?**

This came to my attention because, when using the `psrsq()` function to get the Pseudo R-Squared of a model, I received the following error:

> Weights appear to be scaled: rsquared may be wrong

---

**Update: this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69202399/16668515)**

---